# Showing $T(B_X)$ is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, linear-transformations, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a reflexive space and let $Y$ be a normed linear space. Let $T$ be a completely continuous linear operator.i.e $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ weakly implies $T(x_n)\to T(x)$. I want to show that $T(B_X)$ is compact, where $B_X$ is the closed unit ball in $X$.

I proceed like this.

We know that since $X$ is reflexive and $T$ is completely continuous, therefore $T$ is compact. Thus $\overline{T(B_X)}$ is compact. Thus it suffices to prove that $T(B_X)$ is closed. Consider a sequence $(Tx_n)$ in $T(B_X)$. Thus $(x_n)\subset B_X$ and so $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $X$. Since $X$ is reflexive there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ and there exists $x\in X$ such that $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$ weakly. Since $T$ is completely continuous, therefore $T(x_{n_k})\to T(x)$. Here is the problem. How to show that $x\in B_X$ so that $Tx\in T(B_X)$ and so $T(B_X)$ is closed? Please suggest. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just need the following lemma. If $x_n$ weakly converges to $x$ and $||x_n|| \le C$ for all $n$, then $||x|| \le C$.
The proof is that for any continuous linear functional $l \in X^*$ of norm 1, $|l(x)| = \lim_n |l(x_n)| \le \lim_n ||x_n||\cdot ||l|| \le C$, so that $||x|| = ||\hat{x}|| = \sup_{||l|| = 1} |l(x)| \le C$.